# What are the advantages of using Zend Framework 2 Image Captcha?

Tags: zend-framework2, captcha

I think there are two major reasons that's forcing me not to use Zend's Image captcha.

1. It saves the captcha to disk, which I think it reduces performances in every way, compared to the conventional php captcha.
2. The garbage collector, which is necessary to delete the old captcha images, is another waste of resources. Yes, it's necessary but it's a consequent effect of the disk-written captchas.

Now, is there a reason that I should use Zend Framework's Image Captcha instead of a captcha.php?

EDIT:
:D vague, huh? sorry about that. I mean using a php file to generate a png file. i.e. sending the png mime type in the header, and then outputting the image data using imagepng.

If the performance is not an issue at all here, then I suppose there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Define `captcha.php`... there's so many different ways to implement Captchas and in all honesty, performance is a non-issue on login-forms or comment forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to load an image from a html document: external (so another http request) or inline (base64 encoded). The ZF2 image captcha is using the first implementation, so it's build as that's the only method.

You can use another captcha, use ReCaptcha or use your own implementation. I am not sure what you mean with `captcha.php`?